# How do I remove "api-resource-controller" from my openapi swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm currently using the below **openapi-ui** dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

How to remove the **api-resource-controller** from the **openapi-ui swagger** screen?

[image]

Comment: You question is not clear? Do you want to remove the tag or all the endpoint ?

Comment: I want to remove all the endpoint under api-resource-controller.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to hide certain paths, you could use the `springdoc.paths-to-exclude property`, documented [here](https://springdoc.org/#springdoc-openapi-core-properties).

So, in your case you should use:

```
# Paths to exclude
springdoc.paths-to-exclude=/swagger-resources/**
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `@Hidden` annotation from swagger-annotations, on the top of the controller you want to hide.

Or you can use [properties to filter the endpoints](https://springdoc.org/#selecting-the-rest-controllers-to-include-in-the-documentation) to show, filtering by path or package:

```
# Packages to include
springdoc.packagesToScan=com.package1, com.package2
```

or

```
# Paths to include
springdoc.pathsToMatch=/v1, /api/balance/**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `@EnableSwagger2` from your swagger config file or openapi config file then these openapi-resource controller will authomatically be removed.

Comment: That worked for me.